# $$ in a script vs $$ in a subshell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

`$$` gives process id of the script process when used in a script, like this:

Example 1

```
#!/bin/bash
# processid.sh
# print process ids

ps -o cmd,pid,ppid
echo "The value of \$\$ is $$"

$ ./processid.sh 
CMD                           PID  PPID
bash                        15073  4657
/bin/bash ./processid.sh    15326 15073
ps -o cmd,pid,ppid          15327 15326
The value of $$ is 15326
```

Observe the pid given by `$$` and `ps` is **15326**

My shell prompt is pid **15073**

But in a subshell, `$$` gives pid of parent shell (which is 15073)

Example 2

```
$ ( ps -o cmd,pid,ppid ; echo $$ )
CMD                           PID  PPID
bash                        15073  4657
bash                        15340 15073
ps -o cmd,pid,ppid          15341 15340
15073
```

Here subshell is pid **15340**

Question: Why so? Isn't the script also running in a subshell? What's the difference between the subshell in example 2 and the shell in which the script runs in example 1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried and escaping (to pass the $$ to the subshell) does not work as the subshell inherits the $$ value from the parent bash. The solution to this is to use $BASHPID.

```
(echo $$; echo $BASHPID)
```

prints the PID from the parent shell and from the subshell.

Answer (score 9):

From the bash manpage:

```
   $      Expands  to  the  process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it
          expands to the process ID of the current  shell,  not  the  sub-
          shell.
```

Comment: Now how would I get the value of $$ in the subshell, so that I get the pid of the subshell ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994762/how-can-i-get-the-pid-of-a-subshell-in-bash3-x

Answer (score 6):

The replacement takes place in the parent shell; the subshell hasn't been started by the time the substitution takes place.

Comment: Can you please be little more descriptive please ? I am not able to follow what you are saying. Thanks!

Comment: @abc: Because your subshells never sees the $$. It got invoked with `( echo 1234 )` as your parent shell already substitutes the $$ with its PID. you have to escape it, so the subshell can see the $$.

Comment: @flolo How do I escape it. Can you please give the code ? I tried \$$, $\$. That did not do anything.

Comment: I don't think you can escape it. You can use `$BASHPID` as mentioned above, or the more portable `sh -c 'echo $PPID'`.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't about who does the replacement; $$ *is* evaluated in the subshell, it just intentionally evaluates to the PID of the main shell as the manpage says.

Answer (score 1):

A more portable way, linux-only, but also compatible with dash:

```
read -r my_pid _ < /proc/self/stat
echo $my_pid
```

Comment: It was worring me because `$BASHPID` is only for bash!
`sh -c 'echo $$;echo $$&&sleep 5&sleep 1;echo $!'`
I want the second number be equals to the third, and `$BASHPID` is blank, so:
`sh -c 'echo $$;read a _</proc/self/stat&&echo $a&&sleep 5&sleep 1;echo $!'`
works, thanks!