# How can I get the PID of a subshell in bash3.x?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to get `$BASHPID` value in bash3.x?

Actually, I cannot find any description about it in bash3.x man, but it's available in bash4.x.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's about subshell problem.

Comment: See also this [thread](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2004-12/0151.html). There is no builtin way to get the pid of a subshell (in bash3) because there is never a good reason to have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try: `bash -c 'echo $PPID'`. This works for me on bash 4.1:

```
$ echo $$
8792
$ ( echo $BASHPID; echo $(bash -c 'echo $PPID') )
12987
12987
```

Comment: It's PID of the shell’s parent. I need current subshell's PID

Comment: That's why you run it in a new subshell with `$(bash -c ... )`; the new subshell's parent is the current (sub)shell. Works for me in bash v3.2.48.