# How to get the process id of a bash subprocess on command line

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, process

I know in bash we can create subshells using round parenthesis `(` and `)`. As per bash man page:

```
(list) list  is  executed  in  a  subshell environment
```

Also to get the **current process id** we use:

```
echo $$
```

Now my question is how to get process id of a subshell created using `(` and `)` on command line?

If I use this:

```
echo $$; ( echo $$; )
```

I will get the **parent shell's process id printed twice** on stdout since `$$` gets expanded even before subshell is created. So how to really force the lazy expansion?

**[Solution should work on Mac as well not just Linux]**

### Update:

Suggested linked answer doesn't work since `echo $BASHPID` **does not work** on my Mac and returns blank.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615570/in-a-script-vs-in-a-subshell

Comment: @pilcrow: It is no way duplicate since `echo $BASHPID` doesn't work on my Mac and I mentioned it clearly in my question that `[Solution should work on Mac as well not just Linux]`

Comment: I believe BASHPID requires Bash 4, and OS X ships with Bash 3.2

Comment: @anubhava: True, but we (the SO community) didn't know that until you edited ;-)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Not really, I always had this line `[Solution should work on Mac as well not just Linux]` in my question and also included tag osx in my question.

Comment: Yes, but there is no indication in the other question that the solution provided there doesn't work on a Mac. That's the key point that makes this not a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Agreed. Just fyi I just provided answer to my question here.

Comment: Interestingly, the reason $$ does not work in the subshell is not exactly what you have indicated in your question.  If the problem were just that $$ is being expanded before the subshell code is executed, you could easily solve this by doing (eval echo '$$') but in fact, that doesn't work either.  Accorinding to the very last footnote on http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html, $$ simply returns the pid of the top level, period.  It doesn't indicate why, though.  I don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: NB that if you just want to get a sub process PID (not one from within parentheses) that's easy and available: http://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to all of you for spending your valuable time in finding answer to my question here.

However I am now answering my own question since I've found a *hack* way to get this pid on bash ver < 4 (will work on all the versions though). Here is the command:

```
echo $$; ( F='/tmp/myps'; [ ! -f $F ] && echo 'echo $PPID' > $F; )
```

It prints:

```
5642
13715
```

Where 13715 is the pid of the subshell. To test this when I do:

```
echo $$; ( F='/tmp/myps'; [ ! -f $F ] && echo 'echo $PPID' > $F; bash $F; ps; )
```

I get this:

```
5642
13773
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
 5642 s001  S      0:02.07 -bash
13773 s001  S+     0:00.00 -bash
```

Telling me that 13773 is indeed the pid of the subshell.

**Note:** I reverted back to my original solution since as @ChrisDodd commented that `echo $$; ( bash -c 'echo $PPID'; )` doesn't work Linux. Above solution of mine works both on Mac and Linux.

Comment: `sh -c 'echo $PPID`' is a shorter way to do the same

Comment: One oddity: when I run `echo $$; ( bash -c 'echo $PPID'; )` on my computer (Linux), it prints the same pid twice...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Very valid observation, I reverted back to my original solution.

Comment: @ChrisDodd the command group isn't run in a subshell as its command list contains only one command (this is an undocumented optimisation).  Use `echo $$; (:; bash -c 'echo $PPID')` to force a subshell.

Comment: @ChrisDodd If you tried it from shell then it works as expected. Try this to see different values:  `( echo $$; ( sh -c 'echo $PPID'; ) )` it works for me under ubuntu 12.04 as well as OSX 10.9.2

Comment: Personally this worked for me ```echo $$; (echo 'echo $PPID' | bash)```  just another variation of the above.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this prior to bash version 4, when $BASHPID was introduced.  One thing you can do is to write a tiny program that prints its parent PID:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", getppid());
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile that as `ppid` and put it in your path, you can call it, eg:

```
$ (echo $$; ppid)
2139
29519
$ (x=$(ppid); echo $x)
29521
```

One oddness I noticed, however, is that if you write

```
$ (ppid)
```

it doesn't seem to actually run it in a subshell -- you need at least two commands inside the parentheses for bash to actually run them in a subshell.

Answer (score 5):

You can do :

```
$ ( your_action ) &
[1] 44012
```

And find subprocess' PID like that :

```
$ echo "The sub PID : $!"
The Sub PID : 44012
```

`$!` returns the last job in background's PID. (see [this manual](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html))

Comment: Good attempt but it gets sub process's id only in next command and outside the sub shell.

Answer (score 2):

Use homebrew to install pgrep on the Mac: brew install pgrep

Check out [Link](https://brew.sh/) to install Homebrew.

Comment: Sorry for posting as an answer to the original unrelated question, but I could not comment on the previous post.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it works:

```
(echo $$; echo  `ps axo pid,command,args | grep "$$" |awk '{ getline;print $1}'`)
14609
17365
```

For whatever reason, OSX is limited and doesnt come with pgrep, or one could do (which works in Linux):

```
 (echo $$; echo  `pgrep -P $$`) 
 14609
 17390
```

Comment: Not really, this will print pid of sub+sub+sub+sub shell because of 3 pipes inside ( and ).

Comment: Anubhava can you look at this problem. It should be easy for you. This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961615/what-to-change-in-htaccess-so-it-stop-showing-subdomain

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ppid` of the parent by echoing out the `BASHPID` of the parent when you first enter the shell, then you background the process and can look up the `pid` via `ppid` using the parent `pid`.

E.g. To get the pid of a `sleep 555` command backgrounded within a subshell:

`(echo "$BASHPID" > /tmp/_tmp_pid_ && sleep 555 &) && ps -ho pid --ppid=$(< /tmp/_tmp_pid_)`