# Bash get process ID of a process started in subshell

Tags: bash, shell, process, subshell

I am looking at this question here, but it does not seem to be working for me: [How to get the process id of a bash subprocess on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119885/how-to-get-the-process-id-of-a-bash-subprocess-on-command-line)

So I have a command I start in a subshell, like:

```
(sleep 10 &)
```

How can I then get the process ID of that sleep command, and wait for it?

If I do ps after none of the process IDs from the link above match what I see.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parents are the only process that can properly wait for a child to finish, so you'll want to do the waiting from the subshell.

```
(sleep & wait)
(sleep & pid=$!; wait $pid)
```

Comment: Or don't create a subshell in the first place -- leave out the parentheses.