# Spawning background process under different user in bash

Tags: bash, centos

I know I can run this command to spawn a background process and get the PID:

```
PID=`$SCRIPT > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
```

and to run a command under different user:

```
su - $USER -c "$COMMAND"
```

I don't want the script to run as root and I can't quite figure out how to combine the two and get the PID of the spawned process.

Thanks!

Comment: Why login as _root_ and then `su` as _non-root_ user to run the process?  Why login as _root_ in the first-place?

Comment: this is for init script

Comment: See the following:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119885/how-to-get-the-process-id-of-a-bash-subprocess-on-command-line
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables

Comment: @t0x13: Could your problem be related to premature expansion of the `$!` reference, i.e., that it is expanded before the actual command is executed by `su`? If I run the following simple test on CentOS 6.5, I consistently get non-empty results: `PID=$(su $USER -c ': & echo ${!}'); echo $PID` - note how the command is protected by single quotes to prevent premature expansion. Inside a _double_-quoted string, use `\$!`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `runuser` command. General syntax:

```
runuser -l  userNameHere -c 'command'
```

I suspect that if you set your $SCRIPT variable to the above (with appropriate changes), your first command will do what you want.

Comment: I get `runuser: command not found` and sorry I still don't understand what you're suggesting?

Comment: just to be clear I can do something like PID=`su - $USER -c "$SCRIPT > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"` and the process will spawn just fine but I can't get the PID (it's empty), which I'd get with "$!"

Comment: Some background: `runuser` apparently only comes with [Red Hat Linux derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_derivatives#List_of_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_derivatives), such as RHEL, Fedora, and CentOS (though the OP appears to have a possibly older CentOS version that doesn't have it). It's a simplified `su` that requires no password, but must be run as root; some more info [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.selinux/15848).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on: See the following: - stackoverflow.com/questions/9119885/…

See particularly the following quote from Chris Dodd:

> Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this prior to bash version 4, when $BASHPID was 
>   introduced. One thing you can do is to write a tiny program that prints its parent PID:...

If you have bash 4 and BASHPID, see [$$ in a script vs $$ in a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615570/in-a-script-vs-in-a-subshell)

I don't have version 4, so I can't provide an example of it's usage.

Or write a tiny C program which execvs it's arguments and make it setuid to `USER`.
Or even make a setuid shell script (not generally recommended). Hopefully the `USER` is fixed; if not, get the source for `runuser`, this is essentially what runuser (not a POSIX command) does.

```
PID=`su - $USER -c "$SCRIPT > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"`
```

The problems with the your use of `su` (above) include:

- the `$!` is being executed in the context of the `-c` sub-shell of `su`, not the current shell where `PID` is,
- you're requesting that your `SCRIPT` be run as a login shell, so you don't even know if `USER`'s shell supports `$!`,
- you have no control over the parent-child process chain that `su` (and the user's shell) create.

IOW, when you use

```
PID=`$SCRIPT > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
```

there's only one program involved, `bash`, and two (maybe three?) processes that you pretty much have complete control over. When you throw `su` into the mix, that changes things much more than is apparent on the surface -- `bash` and `su` support similar arguments, right?!?
For obvious reasons, `su` does mucho magic to protect it and its' children's environment  from attacks; it doesn't even like being put in the background....

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will check out the links.

Comment: @kingolego: The immediate problem with your `su` command is that the `$!` is expanded right away by the _original_ shell, due to enclosure in `"`. To truly pass it through to the shell that `su` invokes (as the target user), you'd have to use `\$!` instead (alternatively, use single quotes). You can verify the problem in a simplified scenario without `su` by comparing the following two commands interactively: `bash -c ": & echo ${!}"` vs. `bash -c ": & echo \${!}"` - only the latter will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of late, but here is a two liner will work, seems to need to be two so that it doesn't wait for the $SCRIPT to complete:

```
su $USER -c "$SCRIPT 2>&1 & >> $LogOrNull echo $! > /some/writeable/path"
PID="$(cat /some/writeable/path)"
```

`/some/writeable/path` will need to be writeable by $USER
And the user running these commands will need to have read access